# drop down - use jquery in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fill up the state ddl on selection of a country from a dropown. I am able to get the filter result based on countryname criteria in `stateList` function. But when it returns to view, it shows all the states list. Can you tell me where it went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
//This is my controller class 
public ActionResult  Country()
{
    Country country = new Country();
    ListCountry objCountry = new ListCountry(country);
    return View(country);
}

//This method calls  on selection of countryanem   
public ActionResult stateList()
{
    Country country = new Country();
    var state = Request.Form["_countryId"];
    country.CountryId = _countryId; 
    ListCountry objCountry = new ListCountry(country);
    return View(country);
}
}

//This  is model class  
public partial class Country
{
    public SelectList countryList { get; set; }
    public SelectList stateList { get; set; }
}

public partial class ListCountry
{
    Entities db = new Entities();

    //This constructorof Listcounty  populate the country and state ddl 
    public ListCountry(Country country) 
    {
        string cntId1    = country.countryId;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(cntId1);
        country.countryList = new SelectList(db.Countries.ToList(), "CountryId", "CountryName");
        if (id > 0 )
        {
            List <State> list = db.States.Where(p => p.countryId == id).ToList();
            country.stateList = new SelectList(list, "StateID", "StateName");
        }
        else
        {
            country.stateList = new SelectList(db.States.ToList(), "StateID", "StateName");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see what code path is executing? I would assume you're getting back all  the states because `id` is not greater than zero. How is the `stateList` action being called? If it's jQuery, can you post that code? Also, what does stateList.cshtml look like?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. From your description it looks as though you are calling `stateList` when you first load. Are you including the Country in your call? If you do not it will always give you all the states lists as it needs a `country.countryId` in your query.
2. I don't recommend declaring `SelectList` in your model. MVC is supposed to separate those two concerns. What would happen if all the sudden you decide not use a select? This should only concern the `View`.